# Array_search to echo string

Tags: arrays, string, search

Having problems echo'ing my array seach to return a string instead of it's position in the array. If that makes sense.

echo "
The 5th lang is ";
echo array_search ("Ruby",$myArray);

So basically my echo is returning "The 5th lang is 5" instead of "Ruby".

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: what is `$myArray` contents?

Comment: $myArray = array ( 1=> "C", "Java", "C++ ", "Objective-C", "C#", "PHP","(Visual)
                   Basic", "Python", "JavaScript", "Perl", "Ruby",
                  "PL/SQL", "Delphi/Oject pascal","Visual Basic.Net",
                 "lisp", "Pasca", "Ada", "Transact-SQL", "Logo", "NXT-G");

Comment: what if `Ruby` is not in the array? what should be the output?

Comment: Sorry I'm not exactly sure what you're asking I'm new to this

Comment: Found the soloution, all I had to do was echo ($arr[7]);